# How can I get the class name with contain 'map' in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone how can I get the class name with contain word 'map' with jquery? I'm using the following code to get the class name with map (eg. class="mapTest"), but it not work if the class contain 2 name (e.g class="abctest map test"). Does anyone know how can I fix it?

```
     $(":input[class^=map]").each(function(index, element) {
        map_array.push(this.className);
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried the contains selector? It checks the class name to see if it contains a specified substring. For example:

```
$('input[class*="map"]');
```

See if that works.

More here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 4):

You were close, you want `*=`, not `^=`:

```
$(':input[class*="map"]').each(function(index, element) {
    map_array.push(this.className);
});
```

This is the "attribute contains" selector ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)).

---

About the quotes: They're *optional* if the value you're searching for fits the definition of a [CSS identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (your `map` value does, for instance). They're *required* if you're matching something that doesn't fit that definition (like anything with a space in it, or starting with an unescaped digit).

Since quotes are never *wrong*, best to always use them, but you don't *have* to if you know you're looking for a simple thing like `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `~=` instead. It checks for if it contains the text in cases of multiple classes.

```
$(":input[class~=map]").each(function(index, element) {
        map_array.push(this.className);
    });
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I should clarify. This is for matching when there are multiple classes. (If you had class="map blahmap") it would match map only, where-as `*=` would match both - This is more useful when you're trying to check if something has a specific class name amongst multiple classes)

Comment: This won't match `mapTest`, only `map`. `~=` matches full words.

Comment: `~=` doesn't check for "map" as a substring, but as an element in a white-space delimited list: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation This is handy when working with CSS classes generally, but the OP gave the example of a class "mapTest", which this won't match.